# crontab still sending emails even with > /dev/null

Tags: linux, email, crontab

I have a crontab (root) that runs a script and output is set to > /dev/null but I always get the emails whenever it runs. I only want to receive error emails.

```
# Rackspace driveclient update (12pm MST)
0 12 * * * /root/scripts/driveclient-update > /dev/null
```

The only way I can get it to turn off is to use > /dev/null 2>&1 but then I won't get error emails. This is happening on three different CentOS servers, two are 6.3 and one is 6.4.

***NOTE***: I have read over and over that > /dev/null is supposed to send stdout there and prevent the email if there is nothing but stdout from the script, so at works for at least some people; I cannot figure out why it is not working on these servers.

Here's an example of where > /dev/null is supposed to work:

##### Using the `MAILTO` variable

> The `MAILTO` variable allows you to set the email address that the notification emails from Cron are sent to. You can suppress all emails from your Cron jobs by setting this to an empty string like so:
>
> ```
> $ crontab -e
> ```
>
> Now on the top of the file, add:
>
> ```
> MAILTO=""
> ```
>
> Then save and close the file.

##### Sending output to `/dev/null`

> The `/dev/null` location in Linux is a "black hole" for data: any output sent here is gone, which makes it a great candidate for suppressing output from Cron jobs.
>
> To suppress all output (STDOUT and STDERR) from your Cron job, append `> /dev/null 2>&1` to the end of your job:
>
> ```
> $ crontab -e
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> */30 * * * * command  > /dev/null 2>&1
> ```
>
> The number 2 represents the STDERR (standard error) stream, while 1 is the STDOUT (standard out) stream.
>
> If you want to receive emails about errors only but not successes, append > /dev/null to your job to suppress output from STDOUT only:
>
> ```
> */30 * * * * command > /dev/null
> ```

Originally from [alphadevx.com - Suppressing Cron Job Email Notifications](http://web.archive.org/web/20150321205912/http://www.alphadevx.com/a/384-Suppressing-Cron-Job-Email-Notifications) (link is now dead)

Comment: Here is a perfect example of the behavior I'm looking for: http://www.alphadevx.com/a/384-Suppressing-Cron-Job-Email-Notifications
Specifically the section: "If you want to receive emails about errors only but not successes..."
Why does this not work on our CentOS servers?

Comment: Just to be sure, your script is actually doing what it should, right? Please redirect STDOUT and STDERR to different files and check them afterwards. It probably just writes everything to STDERR.

Comment: The script merely runs yum and wget; all output from those programs are emailed, and it's just normal output they print when running them manually on the command line. I have no explanation for why cron is ignoring > /dev/null for stdout for the programs but not when I use 2>&1 after that; it wouldn't make sense that the script's yum and wget output is being processed as STDERR if it's just normal output, right? I thought its "yes it's working" output was STDOUT.

Comment: Just to clarify, it is ALL OR NOTHING with this crontab. Anything that uses > /dev/null (or doesn't) always emails everything; anything that uses 2>&1 AFTER THAT never emails anything. I cannot explain this behavior. There must be some configuration somewhere that I am not aware or I am not typing it exactly right.

Comment: Yes yes. Now please append `>/var/log/mycron.log 2>/var/log/mycron.err` and see where that gets us. :)

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear that you are getting emails ***containing the standard output from the script*** even when you specify `> /dev/null`. (I was going to post a comment asking “What do the emails contain?”, but then I saw that you had clarified that _in a comment_.) Also, forgive me if you’ve already tried this, but what do you get if you do `/root/scripts/driveclient-update > /dev/null` in a terminal? If possible, copy the command from the crontab file, in case that actually has some subtle typo.

Comment: I'm not sure which comment you're referring to, but I thought it was obvious that the standard output was coming from the script and I'm not sure what the alternative would be since I've never seen crontab email output from anything else where > /dev/null was set and I wouldn't even know how to tell the difference. I did discover that the output was coming from stderr from programs being run in the script such as wget and yum, which I did not know they sent normal messages to even though they don't contain anything abnormal. I answered my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered wget and yum send stdout to stderr so I had to pipe everything to log files.

Answer (score 3):

Set MAILTO="you@me.com" in the crontab file. And let your script '*echo*' stderr or stderr when exceptions are thrown by a *$(subshell)*. Anything can happen, so work with return values (0 is OK, anything else is an exception) like in this example:

```
#!/bin/bash
return=$(/usr/bin/curl --silent --show-error --fail "http://server/somestate" 2>&1)
exitcode=$?
if [ $exitcode != 0 ]
then
    echo "ERROR $HOSTNAME $0 $exitcode $return"
    logger "ERROR $HOSTNAME $0 $exitcode $return"
    exit $exitcode
else
    logger "INFO $HOSTNAME $0 $exitcode $return"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: The MAILTO is fine, it's what we want. The problem is crontab is emailing every output, not just stderr, so no matter what I'm echoing in the script, it will output, even if it's coming from a sub-process I have no control over. For instance, I run a yum check update or a wget and it outputs all its normal output and sends me the email. I'm reading everywhere that > /dev/null is supposed to prevent this but it doesn't.

Comment: The trick is to run your scripts or subprocesses quietly, with a quiet/silent flag and redirect normal output to nirwana with > /dev/null. If you still get mail then it is an stderr output, exceptions that you need to solve.

Comment: So every script in every cron that is run must have a silent flag instead of just behaving the way all tutorials I'm reading say it should? Go check that link I added in my original post. Why does it work there but not here? Your solution may work but it is a lot of stuff I have to add for every cron that should just behave the way the system is supposed to work. If cron will redirect 2>&1 then I don't understand why it won't redirect > /dev/null. It is not stderr that is being emailed, it is normal stdout, exactly what comes from yum and wget when things run fine.

Comment: If you set MAILTO="" you won't get it.

Comment: C'mon guys read the original post. I want emails only when there's an error.

Answer (score 1):

`>` only redirects std out/err, email is an internal function to the script most like.
check the script `-h` for optional parameters or rackspace utility documents

Comment: > just redirects; > /dev/null is supposed to redirect stdout to /dev/null; 2>&1 redirects stderr to stdout, which I don't want. 

I wrote the script, I did not add a line to send an email. The email is coming from Cron Daemon. Please explain. Running the script with -h just runs the script (because I didn't program that option).

Comment: email has nothing to do with stdout or stderr, thus redirecting those will not affect emails.  Check your environment variables; is MAILTO set? `env`

Comment: You're not understanding; I want ONLY errors sent through email. Otherwise I don't want an email sent.

Answer (score 0):

For later referance. You don't have to send everything to a logfile. It is possible to tell bash to also send output on STDERR to /dev/null.

```
# Rackspace driveclient update (12pm MST)
0 12 * * * /root/scripts/driveclient-update > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Note that all I did was append `2>&1` to the end of the file.